# How to set Surface to TvView?

Tags: android, react-native, surfaceview

Is there any possibility, to set your own SurfaceView for TvView?

TvView dont have any method like `setDisplay` or `onSurfaceCreated`.

We have a system where every player has own surface and now we trying to implement a new player (provided by customer) which can play live encrypted multicast. Customer provided us TvView, on which I call `tune` when I want to play something. I build player logic on top of TvView, but I cant integrate it to our system, because we have our own SurfaceView, which can react on react-native events (rise on top and hide).

Is there any possibility to say TvView that is should use custom SurfaceView?

Comment: Hi  @Maltsev Konstantin, working on to set surface to TvView any update please??

Comment: No updates, sorry man

Answer (score 0):

TvView is extending ViewGroup only.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/tv/TvView.
So for the above purpose, you can have a parent layout, to which you can add your surface view or TVView as per playback.